# What else beyond convnets is needed to detect sameness in a Bongard problem?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

In her book Artificial Intelligence - A Guide for Thinking Humans, Melanie Mitchell explains that convolutional neural networks fail to build a useful model for these two classes of images, yielding chance classification for unseen images.

[image]

Image from: https://www.foundalis.com/res/bps/bongard/p057.htm

This surprises me because convolutional networks look very close to the idea embedded in the images: they can detect an object regardless of its position. If splitted in two convenient regions, and taking any of them as a filter, the other region would be perfectly detected in the sameness case, and would yield a low match in the different class.

How should this additional step of splitting be added to the convnet classifier to be able to model sameness?

Comment: if they don't pay attention to position, how can they know whether they have two objects or the same object twice?

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean attention as in transformers?

Comment: no I just mean whether the position matters or not

Comment: to combine CNN outputs into a single number result you could use a dense layer but it won't generalize well to different arrangements of objects; or you could use a max pooling layer but that can't tell the difference between 1 object and 2 objects

Comment: Without the splitting, I think that convolving the negative image with itself, then normalizing the maximum wrt the energy of the image, yields about 1/2 for sameness and close to 0 for different.

Comment: CNNs don't convolve images with themselves. They convolve images with weights. Convolving an image with itself is closer to what attention (as in transformers) does

Comment: Yes. So in this scheme (ACNN, autoconvolutional neural networks), one single parameter is to be learned, the threshold to separate classes. This would be translation invariant, but not wrt rotation or size change.